# difference awk print $1, .. $NF and print $0

Tags: awk

```
echo "a b c  d" | awk '{print}'
```

or

```
echo  "a b c  d" | awk '{print $0}'
```

returns `a b c  d`.

```
echo "a b c  d" | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}'
```

returns `a b c  d`

Are there any ways  to simply do `$1, $2, $3, $4` as `$hoge` alternatively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of `echo "a b c  d" |awk '{print}'` (or `{print $0}`) the record $0 does not get rebuilt but is outputed as is. If you'd like it rebuilt:

```
$ echo "a b c  d" |awk '{$1=$1; print}'
a b c d
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html:

> It is important to remember that $0 is the full record, exactly as it
>   was read from the input. This includes any leading or trailing
>   whitespace, and the exact whitespace (or other characters) that
>   separates the fields.